# Scaling with cairo causes painted image to appear on a different position

Tags: c, gtk, scale, transformation, cairo

I have a pretty simple setup:
Everything happens within overridden "draw" method of a GtkDrawingArea placed inside a viewport in a scrolled window. The drawing area size is 1000000x1000000. It draws a pixbuf centered at the center of the drawing area with:

```
cairo_set_source_surface(cr, pixbufSurface, xPos, yPos); // middle center

cairo_pattern_set_filter(cairo_get_source(cr), CAIRO_FILTER_FAST);

cairo_paint_with_alpha(cr, transp);
```

The problem is that I have to use `cairo_scale()` to simply scale the drawn pixbuf, while still keeping it at the same position, but it moves it very far away instead. The scaling is by virtue of a `scaleFactor` variable. I suspect that I'll have to move the transformation matrix and I brute-forced some values:

1. `cairo_translate(cr, -500000, -500000);` which works if scaleFactor is 2
2. `cairo_translate(cr, -1500000, -1500000);` which works if scaleFactor is 4

but I have no idea how the numbers are correlated to each other.

Comment: If your draw area is 1000000x1000000, and you're at the center, does that mean you're at 500000x500000? If you then scale with a factor of 2, then it makes sense that the middle is moved to 1000000x1000000. You're not scaling from the middle out, but from a corner, I guess.

Comment: Yes, that is the center. What do you mean? The first time I scale with a factor of 2, it works if I translate to -500000x-500000 but if the first time I scale with a factor of 4, it works if I translate to -1500000x-1500000 No idea how to formulize this though

Answer (score 1):

If you're at position (x,y) first, and scale with z, then afterwards you're at (z*x, z*y).

You're at the center, so at (500000, 500000), so if you scale with 2, you'll end up at (1000000, 1000000) and if you scale with 4, you'll end up at (2000000,2000000)

So you can transform back afterwards with ((1-z) * 500000, (1-z) * 500000)

```
cairo_scale(cr, scaleFactor, scaleFactor); 
cairo_translate(cr, 500000 * (1-scaleFactor), 500000 * (1-scaleFactor));
```

You can also transform first with (-500000, - 500000), then scale, and then transform back with (500000, 500000), but that only works in certain cases.

```
cairo_translate(cr, -500000, -500000);
cairo_scale(cr, scaleFactor, scaleFactor); 
cairo_translate(cr, 500000, 500000);
```

Just check if any of that works, or if you encounter other problems.

Comment: So `cairo_translate(cr, 500000 * z, 500000 * z); cairo_scale(cr, z, z); cairo_translate(cr, 500000 * (1-z), 500000 * (1-z));`?

Comment: Ok, in what way? Which one?

Comment: Neither, the pixbuf just disappears (it is moved somewhere in the drawing area) and since it is so big it isn't easy to navigate and find where is it exactly.

Comment: But if scaleFactor=2 then `cairo_translate(cr, 500000 * (1-scaleFactor), 500000 * (1-scaleFactor));` is exactly equal to your example of `cairo_translate(cr, -500000, -500000);`

Comment: It works if the translate function comes before the scale, but it is the opposite in your example?

Comment: Yes, but why. I mean there must be a defined theory behind all that

Comment: I'd need it to happen after scale, because I want to scale once and translate all pixbufs (because there will be more, each on different position). If I scale/translate for every pixbuf each will grow exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what Gnoom said with a few additions:

1. Perform `cairo_scale(cr, z, z)` before drawing pixbufs
2. For every pixbuf being drawn, add `cairo_translate(cr, (xpos*(1-z)/z), (ypos*(1-z)/z));` prior to rendering
3. After rendering `cairo_translate(cr, -(xpos*(1-z)/z), -(ypos*(1-z)/z));`

Answer (score 0):

N.B. If you are rendering several images in the same cairo context, some of which are scaled, remember to save and restore the cr before and after each scaled image or the scaling changes will hang around for the subsequent images drawn after the scaled image. Took me a while to work that one out...

```
        cairo_save (cr);
        
        ...

        cairo_restore (cr);
```